# Reading URL is not works for every URL

Tags: inputstream, bufferedreader, urlconnection, inputstreamreader

I used following method to read a URL. It works fine for most of the URLs. But for some URL it gave an error.

As a example for `http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/father.html`  URL it gave an error as,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/father.html
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at test.TestURL.main(TestURL.java:22)
```

My code is,

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.text.Document;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

    public class TestURL {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            URL x = new URL("http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/father.html");

            URLConnection yc = x.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

            in.close();
        }
    }
```

What is a solution for read every URL using above code?

Comment: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 - probably it's a server-side issue

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But, as I noticed HTTP response code is differ from URL to URL.

Comment: Yes they Differ, but they have a reason for every return code, example 200 for OK, 400 bad request etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.